# Inferring nested value types with consideration for intermediate optional keys

Tags: typescript, type-inference, mapped-types, conditional-types

I'm trying to define helper types for determining the type of nested object values, whilst also considering any optional parent keys, e.g. in structures like these (or deeper):

```
type Foo = { a: { b?: number; } };

type Foo2 = { a?: { b: number } };
```

For my purposes, the type of `b` in both `Foo` and `Foo2` should be inferred as `number | undefined`. In `Foo2` the `b` is not optional itself, but because `a` is, for my lookup purposes `b` must now be optional too... so much for context.

Using these helper types (extracted from a [larger set](https://github.com/thi-ng/umbrella/blob/develop/packages/api/src/api/keyval.ts)) as building blocks:

```
type Keys<T> = keyof Required<T>;

type IsOpt<T> = T extends undefined ? true : never;

type HasOptKey1<T, A> = A extends Keys<T> ? IsOpt<T[A]> : never;

type HasOptKey2<T, A, B> = A extends Keys<T>
    ? IsOpt<T[A]> extends never
        ? HasOptKey1<T[A], B>
        : true
    : never;

type Val1<T, A> = A extends Keys<T> ? T[A] : never;

type Val2<T, A, B> = A extends Keys<T> ? Val1<Required<T>[A], B> : never;
```

Putting these to good use, we get:

```
type F1 = HasOptKey1<Foo, "a">; // never - CORRECT!
type F2 = HasOptKey1<Foo2, "a">; // true - CORRECT!
type F3 = HasOptKey2<Foo, "a", "b">; // true - CORRECT!
type F4 = HasOptKey2<Foo2, "a", "b">; // true - CORRECT!

// infer type of `a` in Foo
type A1 = HasOptKey1<Foo, "a"> extends never
  ? Val1<Foo, "a">
  : Val1<Foo, "a"> | undefined;
// { b: number | undefined; } - CORRECT!

// infer type of `a` in Foo2
type A2 = HasOptKey1<Foo2, "a"> extends never
  ? Val1<Foo2, "a">
  : Val1<Foo2, "a"> | undefined;
// { b: number } | undefined - CORRECT!

// infer type of `b` in Foo
type B1 = HasOptKey2<Foo, "a", "b"> extends never
    ? Val2<Foo, "a", "b">
  : Val2<Foo, "a", "b"> | undefined;
// number | undefined - CORRECT!

// infer type of `b` in Foo2
type B2 = HasOptKey2<Foo2, "a", "b"> extends never
    ? Val2<Foo2, "a", "b">
  : Val2<Foo2, "a", "b"> | undefined;
// number | undefined - CORRECT!
```

To avoid these repeated conditionals, I wanted to use another helper type:

```
// helper type w/ same logic as used for A1/A2/B1/B2 conditionals
type OptVal<PRED, RES> = PRED extends never ? RES : RES | undefined;

// applied
type OptVal1<T, A> = OptVal<HasOptKey1<T, A>, Val1<T, A>>;

type OptVal2<T, A, B> = OptVal<HasOptKey2<T, A, B>, Val2<T, A, B>>;
```

However, even though it seems to be working for 3 out of 4 cases, `A3` is incorrectly inferred as `never` and I don't understand why:

```
type A3 = OptVal1<Foo, "a">;
// never - WHHHYYY??? (should be same as A1!) <-----

type A4 = OptVal1<Foo2, "a">;
// { b: number } | undefined - CORRECT! (same as A2)

type B3 = OptVal2<Foo, "a", "b">; // number | undefined - CORRECT!

type B4 = OptVal2<Foo2, "a","b">; // number | undefined - CORRECT!
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcA8AVAfFAvFA1vA9gGZQBKEAjgK4CWAThACapoDcAsAFCeiRQCSCAPJhgzLFBRQIAD2AQAdgwRRKiiIWrzGUAPxRgtStABcULQDcItdlw49oACQCGQkXBABGVABooAQQxsPylZBSVYeGR0XX5XURQAbT8AXQxTCysbbnBHF2FgdwAmH39fACFA-xC5RWV3KLROKGaYgXzUJNTqsOUM2iaWwb1nOPcvRJTyxo5BwdMDIwHm9IhLa05s3gA1JwAbcd8A8WCZGvD6sT0J5KgVtay7HKgd3eKUQ6nj7tqIxEvnvZeMhUOiMZidT53TIbDgAenhCMRSMRUAAotInABbMC7CAw+xQABi+Hw4gA3lAnKYKQAjHTpSiYmmZKAAXzZDwJxPwhXJlPpUFpDKZVjZHPxT0JHnEI3yYyQ3N8ACInErWFB4WZVqKALRQADCghIJFR+pQAEJNtBCbzsLK3PAvNzCsrVerNQtoHrDcbTRarUSAMwyvIOkDFRVQFVK7xKmlqlga2H6Qxeg1Gk1my2PXiEgAsIdG8AjJJdUdVyvj7uTnqg3ozfuzAb80rtoYKjoVJNdau+4T6Az0Lyd3fLaoGpmHXfwPYwAB8VGoNFoGDZNUKzIzmbQoAvVAx1JpGIn2fXfVmJbw-LaoPaO55p2XoxhTj0tWtBwD9o-ZxOvyOeVnXdFwPZdj04dcoBpYVtzFPclyPBg63Tc9-VsAkylbW92yKace0rXtXx+AcZhaIc9hLGcxwI6Zli-Sj8KjKtgP3Q8VzXZN5C3UV4NAxDkJ9TM0IDMobzvXDnUYuNCNCYjtX6UjmnI14f2opjx1IycKNU6MaJYhD2IgzjuJ3Xi2O0M8hKbOFkVsuz7NhJYoCMqAAAsIF2SAdwJAB3ZMECxaBdnwABzagAGNKWUSgEG0Qh8B3FtYWvKBwvwRRqGAah0r2BAA3yF4kAABRNAARXwTQAZUqErUVKvtenkmIqtuUhUUq-S+MM2xNScMAcWoRh8pEKd3n8SoCr2JBxM7MaAl8UbDjQVhL2gSaVLmz5sHW6acOLEo-CmBbtM2qAKhW2xm2DbaRsBPCxwuzU+mQgB1Bx3oATS+nQfqgAAKBBXPwShdiQ5koACzFoBcfwPHNABKKAkB1FHUbR9H0dW-wCxu4Ap0kh6OMFKCYNFdkzLApDLMbf7Ieh5Rr3hrGymuqB1oYtTpOrTcRVMkDzKplCrOZnG2dulSCd0rnEyekzOoFgSGwvDggA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be other ways of accomplishing what you're trying to do, but the immediate problem that you're facing is you are accidentally [distributing your conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) in the definition of `OptVal`.  Since `PRED` is a type parameter, the conditional check `PRED extends never ? RES : RES | undefined` will end up splitting `PRED` into its union members, evaluating the conditional for each member, and unioning back together for the result.  And your problem case is when `PRED` is `never`.  You might not think of `never` as being a union type, but for consistency's sake the compiler considers it to be *the "empty union"* ([see this comment on ms/TS#23182](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23182#issuecomment-379094672)) and the output will also be an empty union, aka `never`.

The easiest way to turn off distributive conditional types is to take the naked type parameter `PRED` and "clothe" it in a single-element tuple type like this:

```
type OptVal<PRED, RES> = [PRED] extends [never] ? RES : RES | undefined;
```

And this will make your cases work as desired, I think:

```
type A3 = OptVal1<Foo, "a">; // { b?: number | undefined; }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcA8AVAfFAvFA1vA9gGZQBKEAjgK4CWAThACapoDcAsAFCeiRQCSCAPJhgzLFBRQIAD2AQAdgwRRKiiIWrzGUAPxRgtStABcULQDcItdlw49oACQCGQkXBABGVABooAQQxsPylZBSVYeGR0XX5XURQAbT8AXQxTCysbbnBHF2FgdwAmH39fACFA-xC5RWV3KLROKGaYgXzUJNTqsOUM2iaWwb1nOPcvRJTyxo5BwdMDIwHm9IhLa05s3gA1JwAbcd8A8WCZGvD6sT0J5KgVtay7HKgd3eKUQ6nj7tqIxEvnvZeMhUOiMZidT53TIbDgAenhCMRSMRUAAotInABbMC7CAw+xQABi+Hw4gA3lAnKYKQAjHTpSiYmmZKAAXzZDwJxPwhXJlPpUFpDKZVjZHPxT0JHnEI3yYyQ3N8ACInErWFB4WZVqKALRQADCghIJFR+pQAEJNtBCbzsLK3PAvNzCsrVerNQtoHrDcbTRarUSAMwyvIOkDFRVQFVK7xKmlqlga2H6Qxeg1Gk1my2PXiEgAsIdG8AjJJdUdVyvj7uTnqg3ozfuzAb80rtoYKjoVJNdau+4T6Az0Lyd3fLaoGpmHXfwPYwAB8VGoNFoGDZNUKzIzmbQoAvVAx1JpGIn2fXfVmJbw-LaoPaO55p2XoxhTj0tWtBwD9o-ZxOvyOeVnXdFwPZdj04dcoBpYVtzFPclyPBg63Tc9-VsAkylbW92yKace0rXtXx+AcZhaIc9hLGcxwI6Zli-Sj8KjKtgP3Q8VzXZN5C3UV4NAxDkJ9TM0IDMobzvXDnUYuNCNCYjtX6UjmnI14f2opjx1IycKNU6MaJYhD2IgzjuJ3Xi2O0M8hPNKAYWROz7Ic+ElhsuFkwACwgXZIB3AkAHdkwQLFoF2fAAHNqAAY0pZRKAQbRCHwHcW1ha8oAi-BFGoYBqAyvYEADfIXiQAAFE0ABFfBNABlSoElK1EypuIjwgSPobj0arblIVEqv0vjDNsTUnDAHFqEYAqRCnd5-EqQq9iQcTO2mgJfCmw40FYS9oDmlTls+bAdoWnDixKPwplW7S9qgCpNtsZtgwOybATwsdq0FKCBS4kVTJA8zVzZLb-ALR7gCnSTXo497oM3b64N+sCkMsxsoAACkCzFoBcfxCgASkBsoHqgHaGLU6S3q+2CzIRgSGwvdCnjKYGiaelTwd0snE01CmePh-ikbpoA)

Comment: This makes perfect sense & thank you for reminding me of and explaining this particular aspect of conditional type handling! Works great now!