# Inlining a conditional type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Sorry for what might be a simple question to people more familiar with typesystems. Why does inlining a conditional in typescript give different results?

For example, if I'm using the [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#predefined-conditional-types) conditional, I get different behavior if I inline it vs if I use it as a generic:

```js
// setup
type TUnion = ['foo', 1] | ['baz', 2];
type TDiscriminator = ['foo', any];

// using the conditional generic
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;
type TExtracted = Extract<TUnion, TDiscriminator>; // ["foo", 1]

// inlining the conditional
type TInlined = TUnion extends TDiscriminator ? TUnion : never; // never
```

When I push on this further, it seems that the value of T needs to be passed in:

```js
type ExtractWithU<T> = T extends TDiscriminator ? T : never;
type TExtractedWithU = ExtractWithU<TUnion>; // ["foo", 1]

type ExtractWithT<U> = TUnion extends U ? TUnion : never;
type TExtractedWithT = ExtractWithT<TDiscriminator>; // never
```

Am I missing something really simple?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, it's about the distributive behavior of conditional type which only happens over type parameters

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869412/inferring-nested-value-types-with-consideration-for-intermediate-optional-keys)?  ... of course in that one the distributive behavior was not desired whereas here it is, but it's the same issue and explanation

Comment: Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382306/typescript-distributive-conditional-types) maybe?  Not sure if this question needs its own answer

Comment: I'm happy to either write up my own answer or close as dupe. Just to make sure I understand, the problem is that when you inline it you aren't getting the distributive property that we want here (i.e. E<A | B> = E<A> | E<B>), without writing a generic, is there anyway to force the distrbutiveness? Or do I have to generalize it?

Comment: You pretty much need a generic type parameter; you could play games with using a dummy generic parameter that takes a default of the type you want, but that's uglier than just using `Extract`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30572](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30572) for possibly related discussion.

Comment: Perfect - went ahead and did my best to type up an answer - let me know if I missed anythign critical.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment chain above with [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) and [Titian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir), the problem is that the generic is being distributed while the inlined one is not.

Concretely

```js
// setup
type TA = ['foo', 1];
type TB = ['baz', 2];
type TUnion = TA | TB;
type TDiscriminator = ['foo', any];

// using the conditional generic
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never; 
type TExtracted = Extract<TUnion, TDiscriminator>; // ["foo", 1]
//              = Extract<TA | TB, TDiscriminator>
//              = Extract<TA, TDiscriminator> | Extract<TB, TDiscriminator>
//              = TA | never
//              = TA

// inlining the conditional
type TInlined = TUnion extends TDiscriminator ? TUnion : never; // never
//            = never, because the union isn't a subtype of the discriminator
```