# Typescript never type condition

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type with a condition based on `never` but I the results are unexpected (Typescript version 4.1.3).

```
type TypeCond<T, U> = T extends never ? {a: U} : {b: U};

let test: TypeCond<never, number>;
```

I have the `TypeCond` that has a simple condition if `T` extends `never`.

I would expect that the type of the `test` variable will be `{a: number}` but actually, the type is `never`.

I'm not sure why... If I replace the `never` with `undefined` or `null` it works as expected. But I need the condition for the `never` type.

Any idea why `test` gets a `never` type instead of `{a: number}`?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869412/inferring-nested-value-types-with-consideration-for-intermediate-optional-keys

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe this is a consequence of the [distributive property of conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) in Typescript. Essentially, `(S | T) extends A ? B : C` is equivalent to `(S extends A ? B : C) | (T extends A ? B : C)`, i.e. the conditional type distributes over the union in the `extends` clause. Since every type `T` is equivalent to `T | never`, it follows that

- `T extends A ? B : C` is equivalent to `(T | never) extends A ? B : C`,
- Which in turn is equivalent to `(T extends A ? B : C) | (never extends A ? B : C)`,
- This is the same as the original type unioned with `never extends A ? B : C`.

So a conditional type of the form `never extends A ? B : C` *must* evaluate to `never`, otherwise the distributive property would be violated.

---

To make your type work as intended, you can use this trick:

```
type TypeCond<T, U> = [T] extends [never] ? {a: U} : {b: U};
```

This avoids the conditional type distributing over `T`, since `[T]` is not a "naked type parameter".

Comment: Good explanation. It is called ["empty union"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23182#issuecomment-379094672) by the developers.