# How to create a conditional intersection based on a generic parameter?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In the follow example

```js
type Message = string

type CommandWithArgsProps<Args> = {
  args: true
  argsRequired: boolean
  resolveFromArgs(args: string[], message: Message): Promise<Args>
}

export type Command<Args extends unknown = never> = {
  name?: string
  description: string
  execute(message: Message, args: Args): Promise<unknown>
} & (Args extends never ? Record<string, never> : CommandWithArgsProps<Args>)
```

I would like

```js
const x: Command = {
  description: "",
  async execute() {
    return ""
  },
}
```

To be valid, however this errors with `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'never'`. When I add the generic parameter I would like to extend the Command type with the CommandWithArgsProps type

Comment: See [this other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65492464/12299000) for an explanation of why `extends never` doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make optional `Args` generic, you should use `void` instead of `never` - `<Args = void>`.

Type: `Record<string, never>` simply means empty object. BEcause it is impossible to create object with key `string` and value `never`. I think it is worth using here just `{}` instead of `Record<string, never>`.

And the last one, if you want check if generic was provided :`Args extends never ? Record<string, never>` , please use `Args extends void ...`.

Complete code:

```js
type Message = string

type CommandWithArgsProps<Args> = {
  args: true
  argsRequired: boolean
  resolveFromArgs(args: string[], message: Message): Promise<Args>
}

export type Command<Args = void> = {
  name?: string
  description: string
  execute(message: Message, args: Args): Promise<unknown>
} & (Args extends void ? {} : CommandWithArgsProps<Args>)


const x: Command<{ arg: number }> = {
  description: "",
  async execute() {
    return ""
  },
  args: true,
  argsRequired: true,
  resolveFromArgs(args: string[], message: Message) {
    return Promise.resolve({ arg: 42 })
  }
}

const y: Command = {
  description: "",
  async execute() {
    return ""
  },
}
```