# Function return type is not assignable to what generics resolve to

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

What's wrong with the following TS code?

```js
interface Animal {
  name: string;
}

interface Human {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

type HumanName = { humanName: string };
type AnimalName = { animalName: string };

export const getDisplayName = <TItem extends Animal | Human>(
  item: TItem
): TItem extends Human ? HumanName : AnimalName => {
  if ("firstName" in item) {
    return { humanName: `${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}` };  // squiggly line
  } else {
    return { animalName: item.name };  // squiggly line
  }
};
```

Hovering over the squiggly lines this is the error I get:

```
Type '{ humanName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TItem extends Human ? HumanName : AnimalName'.ts(2322)
```

Here's the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChlkQ5MIAuZAZzClAHMBuQgX0MNElkRQAkArthAFiyGMCh0AcuSq16TViRxxZ86nQYgW7TmACeABwHC4IORWQBeAsgAW5y5sU7GyNqyOm0GbDhWKHb4yBZYuEFaSrqerIQQAB7GAPZQYMgIKSB0yIwQYAAiwDTGaoZBtsgAPAAqAJKQmMhJkCAAJjR+EXgAPshCIgB8ABTiwE3UDU2EAJRTjRDNrRAdXYMWyAD8A86V1Og9lTZDYiTAMMgjAESS0mBB18igz02zZyTIUAWCUKKhThEUWQAAMACT4CZLAB0dw0FDYyAhUMw0LU8IgbBBcRIAHpcbQAI6CYCMRg4QzIHCgCDiREQHA0FBET5fH5-ezhALAlHQsjWLx4gk0Ymk8mU6kgWkkDheIA).

Snippet inspired by the legendary Matt Pocock's [tips](https://twitter.com/mattpocockuk/status/1513492326555037698).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the type parameter TItem is not known inside the function. One could argue that the compiler could infer it when `item` is narrowed to either Human or Animal. But it doesn't :)

See this terrific answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70553240/64105

You can do it with casts like this:

```
export const getDisplayName = <TItem extends Animal | Human>(
  item: TItem
): TItem extends Human ? HumanName : AnimalName => {
  type X = TItem extends Human ? HumanName : AnimalName;

  if ("firstName" in item) {
    return { humanName: `${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}` } as X; 
  } else {
    return { animalName: item.name } as X;
  }
};
```

Comment: "One could argue that the compiler could infer it when item is narrowed to either Human or Animal. But it don't". Exactly. I was expecting exactly what you said. I feel better now that I know I'm not alone. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that in the function **implementation**, the generic type is **unresolved**, so you can't treat it as an `Animal` or as a `Human` without explicitly casting it.

The generic type is only resolved for the **caller**.

One possible solution to your problem is to leverage [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) in order to write two signatures:

- One strongly typed for the caller
- One loosely typed for the implementation (compatible with the first one in terms of [duck typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system))

```js
interface Animal {
  name: string;
}

interface Human {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

type HumanName = { humanName: string };
type AnimalName = { animalName: string }; 

function getDisplayName<TItem extends Animal | Human>(item: TItem): TItem extends Human ? HumanName : AnimalName
function getDisplayName(item: Animal | Human): HumanName | AnimalName {
  if ("firstName" in item) {
    return { humanName: `${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}` };  // item: Human
  } else {
    return { animalName: item.name };  // item: Animal
  }
}

const animalName = getDisplayName({ name: 'cat' }); // AnimalName
const humanName = getDisplayName({ firstName: 'Guerric', lastName: 'P' }); // HumanName
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChlkQ5MIAuZAZzClAHMBuQgX0MNElkRQAkArthAFiyGMCh0AcuSq16TViRxxZ86nQYgW7TmACeABwHC4IORWQBeAsgAW5y5sU7GyNqyOm0GbDhWKHb4yBZYuEFaSrqezMicMIIgCGDAAPaijBBgACLANMZqhkEAPAAqAJKQmMgQAB6QIAAmNH4ReAA+yEIiAHwAFMA11FU1AJSj1RC1DU2tPc7IAPyLIkHI1OgdQYRJKWmZyNl5BUVwJfJDI+0ByN29FpNrFhvd2wEbRCTAMMgDACJJNIwEEAchQBCJmISCQoDlBFBRKEnOtXAADAAk+GGMwAdMCNBQ2MhsbjMHi1ESIGx0XESAB6BlQmbUR4gcQkiA4Ggob6w+FgRHIsL+SKucl4sjWLyM5nkrZinCc-SEBCZOiinbyWzHHL5QrFIIDULShQAcgQcDA5s843iTNu4ooao1YEczg2dhOBvOlwoJokUmp1HNAHFBNAGAhzQAaZBU0Guc0ABVtbHtyEd7KCQA)

Comment: How would that work just with casting instead of function overloading? Perhaps a predicate would somehow work?

Comment: Well as `TItem` is unresolved it just does not know what type should be returned so I guess you are forced to ``return { humanName: `${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}` } as any;`` and `return { animalName: item.name } as any;`. It makes the implementation less clean IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns an Object that's either
type `HumanName` or type `AnimalName`.

You can explicitly set the return to that and you should have no errors.

```js
export const getDisplayName = <TItem extends Animal | Human>(
  item: TItem
): HumanName | AnimalName  => {
  if ("firstName" in item) {
    return { humanName: `${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}` };
  } else {
    return { animalName: item.name };  
  }
};
```

To be honest you shouldn't need to explicitly set the return - either as I've done above or as you've tried to in your code - as typescript can infer this from the objects returned.

Comment: Right I get it. However this is training material for me so I'd like to know what's the problem with the existing solution. Your solution DOES work but I still haven't figured out why mine breaks.