# How to call method from class by name with passed arguments?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I'am trying call method from instance api class. For that i'am created function `call` with generic types, but  this isn't work

```
type Method2Params = { a: number, b: number }
type Method1Params = { a: number }

class Api {
    method1({ a }: Method1Params): Boolean {
        return a % 2 === 0
    }

    method2({ a, b }: Method2Params): Number {
        return a + b
    }
}

const api = new Api();

function call<
    Method extends keyof Api,
>(
    method: Method,
    ...args: Parameters<Api[Method]>
): ReturnType<Api[Method]> {
    const result = api[method](args); // error
    return result; // error
}

const sign = call('method1', { a: 12 })
```

I'am declare function call with generic types

Comment: Don't have an extra `Fn` type parameter. Just refer to `Parameters<Api[Method]>` and `ReturnType<Api[Method]>` respectively.

Comment: thx, but this isn't work either

Comment: Could you show error you got?

Comment: Run this script on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: [Please use `boolean` and `number` instead of `Boolean` and `Number`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object).

Comment: Related and might be useful to read in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73586791/function-return-type-is-not-assignable-to-what-generics-resolve-to and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70553130/typescript-generic-conditional-type-as-return-value-for-generic-function/70553240#70553240

Comment: Do you have a typo? Shouldn't it be `api[method](...args)` instead?  That doesn't fix your problem but it's a typo nonetheless.

Comment: The compiler can't analyze generic conditional types in the abstract like this; you could refactor as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) to make everything written in terms of generic indexed accesses, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WkE0jN).  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?