# Typescript function whose return type depends on a generic

Tags: typescript, union-types, generic-type-argument

I'm trying to write a function whose return type depends on a generic argument. Here's a snippet of code to demonstrate:

```
type FOOBAR = 'foo' | 'bar';

function fn<T extends FOOBAR>(arg: T): T extends 'foo' ? 'r1' : 'r2' {
  if (arg === 'foo') {
    return 'r1';
  }
  return 'r2';

}

const fooResponse = fn('foo'); // this is correctly typed as 'r1'
const barResponse = fn('bar'); // this is correctly typed as 'r2'
```

Within the function body, I see `Type '"r1"' is not assignable to type 'T extends "foo" ? "r1" : "r2"'.`. It's not clear to me how to resolve this complaint.

I do see a number of related questions, but none which address the combination of dependent return types with union types. [The closest I could find is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70553130/typescript-generic-conditional-type-as-return-value-for-generic-function), which seems to imply that it is currently impossible, though I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't currently narrow generic type arguments via control flow; see [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) for the relevant feature request.  If you want type safety you can refactor to a version which uses generic indexing, which the compiler does understand, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mM8p1N).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use function overloads:

```
type FOOBAR = 'foo' | 'bar';

function fn(arg: 'foo'): 'r1';
function fn(arg: 'bar'): 'r2';
function fn(arg: FOOBAR) {
  if (arg === 'foo') {
    return 'r1';
  }
  return 'r2';
}

const fooResponse = fn('foo'); // this is correctly typed as 'r1'
const barResponse = fn('bar'); // this is correctly typed as 'r2'
```