# Confusing resolution of "never extends" in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
type IsASubsetOfUnknown<T> = T extends unknown ? true : false;

type T1 = IsASubsetOfUnknown<never>; // never
type T2 = never extends unknown ? true : false; // true
```

Why is T1 `never` and T2 `true`? I would expect them to both be true.

Comment: (essentially a) duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492464/typescript-never-type-condition

Comment: you're absolutely right, thanks. I've voted to close it as a dupe