# What's wrong with this Typescript conditional type?

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I have a conditional type where both sides of the condition are identical:

```
type Wut<T> = T extends number ? string | T : string | T
```

(This is not very useful. I'm just trying to understand what's going on.)

I can use the type as expected:

```
const huh1: Wut<number> = 'huh'  // OK
const huh2: Wut<object> = 'huh'  // OK
const huh3: Wut<string> = 'huh'  // OK
const huh4: Wut<number> = 22     // OK
```

... until I try to inherit from other generics:

```
function hmmm<N extends number, S extends string>() {
    const huh1: Wut<N> = 'huh' // <- Type 'string' is not assignable to 'Wut<T>'
    const huh2: Wut<N> = 22    // <- Type 'number' is not assignable to 'Wut<T>'
    const huh3: Wut<S> = 'huh' // <- Type 'string' is not assignable to 'Wut<T>'
}
```

See [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECMHsBcAtQM4EsAmBTBpIDNRzaAMaQB2KS0SpAhgDajUBOBqaJlhdoAdLwLAAoaAE8ADgQDqAV2gAeACoA+UAF5Q80GgAe0NikyRwAKzSFooAPyJojJCQDmoAD6gAFK60AudQEpVykikAW3A0Rj9vBBs7Rxd3L19-UECQsJ9BQRA8WAwCJgIoOFBsOzRBYhIo0FgpWG9pOUMTM2U1AHIa2Dby0iqAdxl6mVko2wdW0A7a7oFBbCkSMyoSaqC1hU0dPQNjU2gAGlAAZU3dMkxRmMVXPwBvQQBICqrOobklVUnOttAs0EfnuYBtA3rIjhMpl1fmBZABaRCQUB9WDCBjMbK5TSMRiQRgICyCAC+QA).

What's wrong with my conditional type here?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure *why* it's erroring, but [disabling distribution](https://tsplay.dev/N73KPN) does solve it.

Comment: Ah, I know now. If you pass `never`, the result is `never`, and nothing is assignable to `never`!

Comment: `N extends number` actually means that it's a more specific form of number. For example, it could be `1 | 2`. With this, 22 wouldn't be a valid number. Same thing goes for `S extends string`. I don't know why `huh1` isn't valid though.

Answer (score 2):

There's an error here because calls like `hmmm<never, never>()` are valid, and `Wut<never>` is reduced to `never`. See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492464/typescript-never-type-condition) for why it produces `never`. Since nothing is assignable to `never`, you get an error. You can fix this by disabling distribution in the conditional:

```
type Wut<T> = [T] extends [object] ? string | ((x: T) => number) : string | ((x: T) => number)
```

Now, `[never] extends [object]` won't distribute, so you'll get `string | ((x: never) => number)`, not `never`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECMHsBcAtQM4EsAmBTBpIDNRzaAMaQB2KS0SpAhgDajUBOBqaJlhdoAdLwLAAoaAE8ADgQDqAV2gAeACoA+UAF5QAbXkBdUGgAe0NikzrI4AFZpC0HQH5E0RkhIBzUAB9QACi96AXKDyAJSqyiRSALbgaIwhAQiOzm6ePv6BISphkdGxgoIgeLAYBEwEUHCg2M5ogsQkCaCwUrAB0nJmltbKagDkTbA9taQNAO4yrTKyCU6u3aB9zYMCgthSJNZUJI0ROwq6BkaYHVbQADSgAMr7hmSY00mKXiEA3oIAkHUN-RNySqrz-R6oAKkAA1tRhKBQO9PtBQGNoD9ZBc5gsBsCwGCIYIAL5AA)