# Is there a way to produce a type that combines field types from a tuple of objects in typescript?

Tags: typescript, tuples, type-inference, zod

I have a structure that describes a specific configuration value:

```
import * as z from 'zod';

export type ConfigurationProperty<V> = {
    type: string;
    // ...
    schema: z.Schema<V>; // Zod Schema
};
```

and it is relatively easy to produce a struct from a bunch of these properties:

```
export const DailyStandupTime = {
    type: "dailyStandupTime" as const,
    schema: z.string(),
}

export const DailyStandupTimeZone = {
    type: "dailyStandupTimeZone" as const,
    schema: z.string(),
};

export const DailyConfig = z.object({
    [DailyStandupTime.type]: DailyStandupTime.schema,
    [DailyStandupTimeZone.type]: DailyStandupTimeZone.schema,
});

export type DailyConfig = z.infer<typeof DailyConfig>;
```

here the `DailyConfig` type will correctly resolve to:

```
type DailyConfig = {
    dailyStandupTime: string;
    dailyStandupTimeZone: string;
}
```

but I'd like to write a general-purpose function that accepts a tuple of `ConfigurationProperty` objects like this:

```
const validate = <T>(data: Record<string, unknown>, props: ConfigurationProperty<any>[]): T => {
    throw new Error("Not implemented");
}


validate({a: 1, b: 2}, [DailyStandupTime, DailyStandupTimeZone]);
```

is it possible to somehow infer the type `T` from the tuple of `ConfigurationProperty` objects?

Comment: Could you either tag this with `zod` or [edit] the code to be a [mre] that doesn't involve third-party libraries?  Ideally we could copy and paste your code into our own IDEs and get to work on the issue without needing to try to handle types or values that are private or from third parties.  Right now if I do that [I get lots of errors](https://tsplay.dev/WP8kkW).  Could you fix those and put the fixed code as plain text in your question?  That would help us get started.

Comment: Sure, I removed all the fluff, now it will compile with zod.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8YzMN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: That's not a solution, unfortunately. Instead of `string | number` it should be `type DailyConfig = {
  dailyStandupTime: string;
  dailyStandupTimeZone: string;
}`

Comment: Check [this one](https://tsplay.dev/Nl8nRN) please

Comment: Wow, what sort of trickery is this? 

Comment: So there is one small problem: what I need is not the schema itself, but the type it resolves to 

Comment: @AdamArold I can suggest something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3vk2N) would that work?

Comment: Or [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXr5Dm)

Comment: Yes, those work, would you put that in an answer? Also, can you explain the trickery that's happening there? My brain hurts just by looking at it 

Comment: Sure will do in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we will need to add a generic parameter for `props` and for the sake of testing let's make the return type `T[number]` which will result in the union of `props''s elements type:

```
const validate = <T extends ConfigurationProperty<any>[]>(
  data: Record<string, unknown>,
  props: T,
): T[number] => {
   return {} as any
};
```

Example:

```
// {
//     type: "dailyStandupTime";
//     schema: z.ZodString;
// } | {
//     type: "dailyStandupTimeZone";
//     schema: z.ZodNumber;
// }
const result = validate({ a: 1, b: 2 }, [
  DailyStandupTime,
  DailyStandupTimeZone,
]);
```

Now, using the [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) we are going to convert `{type: 'value', schema: SomeType}` to `{value: SomeType}`. This type will accept a generic parameter constrained by `ConfigurationProperty<unknown>` that is the type of the `props`'s elements. For this example, we will add a utility type `Prettify` that remaps the given type, which makes the type shown in the IDE readable:

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R
  ? {
      [K in keyof R]: R[K];
    }
  : never;


type MapConfigurationProperty<T extends { type: string; schema: unknown }> = Prettify<{
  [K in T['type']]: T['schema'];
}
```

Let's update the `validate` as follows:

```
const validate = <T extends ConfigurationProperty<any>[]>(
  data: Record<string, unknown>,
  props: T,
): MapConfigurationProperty<T[number]> => {
  return {} as any;
};
```

Example:

```
// const result: {
//     dailyStandupTimeZone: z.ZodNumber | z.ZodString;
//     dailyStandupTime: z.ZodNumber | z.ZodString;
// }
const result = validate({ a: 1, b: 2 }, [
  DailyStandupTime,
  DailyStandupTimeZone,
]);
```

We can see that values in the result have the union of all possible types, which can be fixed by [distributing types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type MapConfigurationProperty<T extends ConfigurationProperty<unknown>> =
  Prettify<
    T extends T
      ? {
          [K in T['type']]: T['schema'];
        }
      : never
  >;
```

The same example will give us:

```
const result: {
    dailyStandupTime: z.ZodString;
} | {
    dailyStandupTimeZone: z.ZodNumber;
}
```

This is pretty close but we need to have these properties in a single object, not a union of one key and one value. To achieve this we are going to use `UnionToIntersection` described by @jcalz in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/21637817):

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I,
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type MapConfigurationProperty<T extends ConfigurationProperty<unknown>> =
  Prettify<
    UnionToIntersection<
      T extends T
        ? {
            [K in T['type']]: T['schema'];
          }
        : never
    >
  >;
```

Now the `result` will be:

```
const result: {
    dailyStandupTime: z.ZodString;
    dailyStandupTimeZone: z.ZodNumber;
}
```

Since you expect to have `string` and `number` instead of `z.ZodString` and `z.ZodNumber` respectively, we will infer the desired type from the latter ones. If we look in the `zod`'s source code in [here](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/blob/master/src/types.ts#L1085), we see that `zodNumber` extends `ZodType<number,...>`, thus we can infer the type from there by checking whether `schema` extends some `ZodType`:

```
type MapConfigurationProperty<T extends ConfigurationProperty<unknown>> =
  Prettify<
    UnionToIntersection<
      T extends T
        ? {
            [K in T['type']]: T['schema'];
          }
        : never
    > extends infer R
      ? {
          [K in keyof R]: R[K] extends z.ZodType<infer Extracted>
            ? [Extracted] extends [never]
              ? R[K]
              : Extracted
            : R[K];
        }
      : never
  >;
```

The inferred type `R` at that moment for the given example will be the same as the `result` in the last code snippet, where the values are `zod` types, thus we can check whether `R[K]`, where `K` is the key of `R` extends some `ZodType` using the [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) keyword, and the inferred type will be declared as `Extracted`. For type safety we will check whether `Extracted` is `never` and this is done as @kaya3 explain in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65492934/21637817). If `Extracted` is `never` we keep the original Zod type, otherwise, we use `Extracted` itself.

Final testing and we get what we need:

```
// const result: {
//     dailyStandupTime: string;
//     dailyStandupTimeZone: number;
// }
const result = validate({ a: 1, b: 2 }, [
  DailyStandupTime,
  DailyStandupTimeZone,
]);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wF5wGZQiOAcgwgBNCBuAKCoFMAPSWOGATzFrgGEIA7bYAHMArlGQxgfAAp4OsVgB4AagD44AXjgBvKnBbtaALjioYUYL0HU9qAMYALWiGTGMAOgDKDp8mUqKcAD0gXAAWmRwXo7OVAC+1HSM0PC2fKZwACLIwAA2rB4wyLykwmAAKqCcmjp6bBzGhKTZeQVFJeWVhCjoqbymADS6Jt7Orm6m5pYAFACUg-E0DEwpafBZufmFxaUVILThvFXaQ3VGRE0brdsdewe0XWhwvQNDdtEumG68wiAARrRQWbzBJLZJPVaZZqsHj8IQaT4QX4AK1othgUxqcAA2usWlt2rtaG5TgBdYy4zZtHaVcYjZCDPQ4qFXAmVO7EgxkyGXfHU258IlvHzzGYgpLMU7cvIwgSCMoGeHuCzYAEKU4QbBS6F8WX+GiSikyuHVIYXPFUm5nCYWKym5m8y13YzWyzUBZUSUAVV4kl4ZQgAEleDAAahURI+ApPWpNFNPXAGCHiugiqw4AB+OBTADWxk9Mw0agAbhBgKQ4MZDkWAQXE7Rk1mhrm4MqAXAA4MC+pi6XSENMwGhpXaNWoAlJTJaDAJNhFGUY3Aygn6EnSOhW1A4AAlfvHPT77EAaRbvDg2dorA1265W6xh5J1n3sSHcCrAPHCoAssgwEaRGII14GQIDkNgFCXOsGz-URxF9YDQMUYReGzXgIAAd14FQYyGSdp2AWcFCGPRvV9f0gxDKAwzRX1CIPPQIJXes10XIi6MzTE6Lou8T0XLFCFOQgSS5Mo+KFZxBMfTi9GfKSK1fEcAVYtRIOYjdt1YvR2I0rjjwsM8LyvLcbzvEll1XdB3HCUh5Q4BQ1IAURXMQ0VoUgVG0zjMyxRyzGQFzSFMlT0CxN8oBJDypMzW97wizjjB85yQz7WSD2MaKHwimS6OHUchj1KhnngItkByMtxCOcCzKY9BoIAuDZABMDUxULESRUKY7UKNLUWgUgFBdQR+jgJCUPQzCGTgMBZFQYwyk7Yxv1-HUhBgwD4MaucQp+f4wpjNRMSgKdRFPLRYm6FBeFYN0EmCcE+ngQ7UGEHIYGMHRboPM1KWuQlnTMG1qA+-cvpZPl9gFSttvfKhbufQq4Ee574E0YrSqaEMMRQYwAEYht+YwACY4FiIasSGClQctCaKYdQk7kGElRSoIA)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the huge amount of work that went into this. I learned a lot about conditional and mapped types today!