# Typescript Argument of type {...} is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Trying to create a function where (from a typing perspective) based on the first two arguments it determines whether a 3rd argument should be provided or not. Whether the 3rd argument is required is based on if a specific nested key exists in the object based on the path of the first two arguments. I created a contrived example to demonstrate:

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQCrmgXigbwCgooArAewAsA7ALgOJKmHPNQCNy578oBjNuQBO9AM7AhAS2oBzKAF9G8gDSNSCahB6MSovkIgB3ACZSAbhBEF+gq+KmyFS1boSpUIbUyiVkSSzw2qMJiEtJyKjpQ1AiSqDyKJIqKhKCQUADCtgCCQjKiADxZwUIAfFB4xcJQEHDAENTGotEQFkJQAPzWAiUd9FXt8lCBPSGZtgoA3ISp2LCIKOgAYtQVUAWMAHLI0LX1jc3wEgh8wAUA1hAg5ABm88homNjKUPbhpS5QGJThNXUNTXmx1OFyut3uiyekAA2tt-ABdF5vWQfRgDP77QEACngD3QWBhcIg8Oh33C8IxAOavFGVmkN0smQUnSZ9E0bQAlIRSliBNQbpIZIEYv56ESXsAfrJ6GTHEMAGTjEq5fJFWylDkVcrImTTQi1MDCYA2ajiP54iArei4yErNZY3giiASqUyF60hSanDlIgkPmiNgQAB0wRkWKdLvC7tsHOmJAMwAArkJVgBySgQdzkVPTeR62oWlYOxhO+ip0RuDypz6S8JlmJxauEeSxwhAA)

```
type ExampleType = {
  john: {
    toolbox: { color: string }
  },
  jane: {
    screwdriver: { color: string }
  },
  sally: {
    hammer: { color: string },
    nail: {}
  }
}

type ColorArgs<Color> = Color extends never ? { color?: Color } : { color: Color };

type ExampleFn = <
  Name extends Extract<keyof ExampleType, string>,
  Thing extends Extract<keyof ExampleType[Name], string>,
  Color extends (ExampleType[Name][Thing] extends { color: infer C } ? C : never)
>(config: { name: Name, thing: Thing } & ColorArgs<Color>) => string;

export const exampleFn: ExampleFn = ({ name, thing, color }) => {
  console.log(name, thing, color);
  return 'hello';
};

exampleFn({
  name: 'sally',
  thing: 'nail',
});
```

I'm expecting the function to work correctly and not allow a color argument when name is sally and thing is nail.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Na5yPN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That works! Thank you! I'm still unsure why the way I did it didn't work. And you're right to point out that Extract part should not have been included in the example.

Comment: It didn't work because `ColorArgs<never>` is `never`, but I don't know why you want `never` in there in the first place. I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there's no real reason for this example that you'd need to have three [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters in your function. Instead of using `Color` as a type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to some type, you can just use that type instead:

```
type ExampleFn = <
  K1 extends keyof ExampleType,
  K2 extends keyof ExampleType[K1]      
>(config: { name: K1, thing: K2 } & ColorArgs<(
    ExampleType[K1][K2] extends { color: infer C } ? C : never
 )>) => string;
```

Then we need to fix the complicated `ColorArgs<( ExampleType[K1][K2] extends { color: infer C } ? C : never )>` to be something that actually works. Your `ColorArgs` type function is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), and those *always* map `never` to `never` in order to be consistent with unions (see the answer to [Inferring nested value types with consideration for intermediate optional keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60869412/2887218) for more information). Since you're apparently trying to use `never` as a sigil to detect when `color` is not a key of the input, then you're getting `never` out instead of your intended type.

So the best way forward here is to completely avoid the intermediate `never`, and just handle both cases separately.  I'd do this:

```
type ExampleFn = <
  K1 extends keyof ExampleType,
  K2 extends keyof ExampleType[K1],
>(config:
  { name: K1, thing: K2, color?: unknown } &
  ColorArgs<ExampleType[K1][K2]>
) => string;

type ColorArgs<T> =
  "color" extends keyof T ? Pick<T, "color"> : { color?: never }
```

Here I'm passing in the full `ExampleType[K1][K2]` for `T`, and then `ColorArgs` checks if `color` is a key of `T` or not. If it is, you get `Pick<T, "color">` to give you the part of `T` with that key, and if not, you get `{color?: never}` to prohibit such a property (it technically makes it an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties) of type `never`, which is somewhat different, but very close to being a prohibition).

The reason I include `color?: unknown` in the type of `config` is just to make sure the compiler knows that it's always safe to index into `config` with `color` no matter what generic types `K1` and `K2` are. Otherwise you'd run into a problem here:

```
export const exampleFn: ExampleFn = ({ name, thing, color }) => {
  console.log(name, thing, color);
  return 'hello';
};
```

where the destructured `color` property wouldn't be recognized as valid.

And now we can check that it works as desired:

```
exampleFn({ name: 'sally', thing: 'nail' }); // okay
exampleFn({ name: 'sally', thing: 'nail', color: "red" }); // error
exampleFn({ name: "jane", thing: "screwdriver", color: "red" }); // okay
exampleFn({ name: "jane", thing: "screwdriver" }); // error
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQCrmgXigbwCgooArAewAsA7ALgOJKmHPNQCNy578oBjNuQBO9AM7AhAS2oBzKAF9G8gDSNSCahB6MSovkIgB3ACZSAbhBEF+gq+KmyFS1boSpUIbUyiVkSSzw2qMJiEtJyKjpQ1AiSqDyKJIqKhISgkLCIKOgAYtRQeAA8jADSAIxQEHDAENTGolAA1hAg5ABmmchomNguUCUATJXVtfVNLe2d2T2QANrlALqqAHwAFALUbZIytIy8Mf705crMlOFHAycCwUIA-PQArtSN1OSG+fJQAGSMAMK2AEEhDJRIV4F10Fg5ot5gMFstCABKArLKD2cIAblS6Wg-xuQJBhQwqJwjAARNdhGThjU6g1mq0OhgoLcoAAFSR8RpEk4U2xk1GBSl3eiaCxCJypKpgYTAGzUcTDCEQPL0cHTPIFKCrfbICAnYBnWRXWwKZE4VFEEgbURsCAAOmCMlWB31p3CJpuiKxJAMwAeQnyAHJKBB3OQg1j5FjCFVlXkddE9fQg6I3B4gwajTsoEGYnEg2aMVAAPQlqDkRoIECxrLdBO6w65tPuECZ92yFP51Dt4X0MkGYzU+Te0vlyxCYS1+PUROu-vqTRkrPnKBkvQGEzmSzLoIhNeD4ejssVqs1uMa2eNrRrxcQXeG1fr-RGUyScVH4snidToA)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I have no idea why it works.

Change this line:

```
type ColorArgs<Color> = Color extends never ? { color?: Color } : { color: Color };
```

to this:

```
type ColorArgs<Color> = [Color] extends [never] ? { color?: Color } : { color: Color };
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQCrmgXigbwCgooArAewAsA7ALgOJKmHPNQCNy578oBjNuQBO9AM7AhAS2oBzKAF9G8gDSNSCahB6MSovkIgB3ACZSAbhBEF+gq+KmyFS1boSpUIbUyiVkSSzw2qMJiEtJyKjpQ1AiSqDyKJIqKhKCQUADCtgCCQjKiADxZwUIAfFB4ANrFwgC6UBBwwBDUxqJQlZoWQvUA-NYCJb30NUIKUIGDIZm2CgDchKnYsIgo6ABi1BVQBYwAcsjQjc2t7fASCHzABQDWECDkAGYryGiY2MpQ9uGlLlAYlHCDSaLTaKwuV1u9yeLzW70glQO-lqn2+sl+jFGwJOYIAFPBXugsAikRBapUAeF6sdQe1eFMrNJHpZMuN+hkJtEIN0AJSEUq4gTUR6SGSBGL+eikz7AQGyeiUxzyKAAMhmJVy+SKtlKPIq5TRMgWhEaYGEwBs1HEwMJEE29AJcM221xvAlEBlcpknwZCj1OHKRBIQtEbAgADpgjJce7PeEfbYeQsSAZgABXIRbADklAg7nIWYW8mNjVtm1djHd9CzojcHizf1l4WrMTiDcI8iTi1LTuoFZIVagWYoNHbJCb8qHLDYnDgY6C0yzBmMWY7SaAA)

Comment: I don't understand why you're using a third type param at all, and why you're trying to set something to `never` just to undo that `never` to become `{color?: never}`. Your change works because it turns off distributivity of the conditional type, but this isn't the way I'd want to implement your code at all, since `never` has essentially nothing to do with your code.  `extends never` in a [distributive conditional type](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) is problematic, but I don't know that this is particularly enlightening here.